# CHVW Table in SAP is not updating for a specific date

Tags: sap-erp

I currently have customized report to show material documents for batch managed materials that can be filtered by material, plant, posting date, etc. This report pulls data from CHVW table.

I tried to generate the material documents list for 08/24/2020 to 08/25/2020 but the report only displays the material documents for 08/24/2020. Upon checking, the standard SAP table CHVW is not updated either for 08/25/2020. But full list of material documents appear in MB51 (Material Documents List).

Where can I check what's causing the CHVW table to not be updated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this isn't really a topic suitable for Stackoverflow. But you'll find your answer here: https://answers.sap.com/questions/12387527/movement-types-for-batch-where-used-list---table-c.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Apologies for posting the topic here but the link helped answer my concern.